# amCharts dynamic data passing

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am trying to pass data into the amCharts dynamically but the data not presented in the chart. The code block is below and this is the simple one :

```
<script>

var chartData = generateChartData();

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("testDiv", {
    "type": "serial",
    "theme": "light",
    dataSets: [{
        fieldMappings: [{
            fromField: "country",
            toField: "country"
        }, {
            fromField: "visits",
            toField: "visits"
        }],

    "dataProvider": chartData,
    "valueAxes": [{
        "gridColor": "#FFFFFF",
        "gridAlpha": 0.2,
        "dashLength": 0
    }],
    "gridAboveGraphs": true,
    "startDuration": 1,
    "graphs": [{
        "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "lineAlpha": 0.2,
        "type": "column",
        "valueField": "visits"
    }],
    "chartCursor": {
        "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
        "cursorAlpha": 0,
        "zoomable": false
    },
    "categoryField": "country",
    "categoryAxis": {
        "gridPosition": "start",
        "gridAlpha": 0,
        "tickPosition": "start",
        "tickLength": 20
    },
    "export": {
        "enabled": true
    }

});



function generateChartData() {

for (var i = 0; i < 3 ; i++) {
    var chartData = [];
    /*
    var a = versionList[i];
    var b = countOfVersion[i];
    */
    chartData.push({
        country: "Canb",
        visits:1
    });
}
return chartData;
}
</script>

<div id="testDiv"></div>
```

How can I pass the data into the chart? I have a method named `generateChartData` and this method produces data which will be used in chart.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this chart displays nothing is that you reset `chartData` array on every iteration of the for cycle:

```
var chartData = [];
```

This results in the data with just one data point. Since your line graph does not have any bullets, you see nothing. (there's no line to draw beteem single data point)

Try modifying this function like this:

```
function generateChartData() {
  var chartData = [];
  for ( var i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
    /*
    var a = versionList[i];
    var b = countOfVersion[i];
    */
    chartData.push( {
      country: "Canb",
      visits: 1
    } );
  }
  return chartData;
}
```

On the related note, the `dataSets` block you have is used in Stock chart only and is ignored in Serial chart. You can simply remove the whole block, as it won't affect the chart in any way.